# Copying build artifacts to a Docker image

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to containerize a console application (windows service) written in c# that exposes WebAPI. The app itself works just fine. I came to the point when I need to create a Docker file and build the image:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
RUN mkdir C:\service #&& cd apiservice
ADD . /service
RUN c:\service\AspNetService.exe install --autostart --localservice
EXPOSE 8080
```

In line 4 the service must be installed in the container but I discovered that 'service' directory is empty, i.e. the build artifacts from the solution weren't copied to the container. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could be because of using `/service` rather than `c:\service`, but I doubt it as long as it knows you're on C:. Is your Dockerfile in the same directory as your build artifacts?

Comment: No, it's in the project directory, where VS place it by default. Should it be copied to /bin/Release/?

Comment: Either that or it should reference the location of the build artefacts in your `RUN` command. The first dot just means it's going to try and copy whatever is in the same directory as your Dockerfile.

Comment: I tried to use "RUN dir c:\service" as a parameter in the fourth line and during the build it shows empty directory, meaning it copies nothing. I was expecting it will copy at least some files.
If I specify "COPY /bin/Release/ ." as a parameter, in the build console I can see it tries to copy files from the absolutely wrong path, i.e.: "COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder491464451\bin\Release: The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Did you do `/bin/release` or `./bin/release`? The former would try and go to the root directory, which I'm guessing is somewhere in the docker stuff judging by the error

Comment: All these variations give the same result, i.e. "COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder491464451\bin\Release: The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173513/discussion-between-john-bull-and-scott-bamforth).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out all the paths but 'obj/Docker/publish/' were blocked by '.dockerignore' which is created automatically with Dockerfile. Once fixed, the issue was solved. I can copy the files with 'ADD ./bin/Release/  .' and see them written to the image.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!